# Fitting time series with unstable time series models

Tags: python, statistics, time-series, data-fitting, autoregressive-models

I am currently fitting time series with autoregressive (AR) models. During the modelling I found some AR models are unstable, namely some modulus values of the AR companion matrix are less than or equal to 1. I knew that unstable AR models could lead to explosions of future predictions. However, when I use the AR models just to fit time series and to extract the AR coefficients for time series classification, is it ok to use unstable AR models? Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated!